# pivot_wider: How to add rows for non unique values?

Tags: r, duplicates, tidyr

I have a table in long format with a species name in different languages and 2 levels of id number, one corresponding to the species, the other to the different names for that species.

for example:

```
species_list <- cbind.data.frame(num_sp= c(100,101,101,101,101,102,102,103), num_name = c(1,1,2,3,4,1,2,1), language=c("latin","latin", "english", "english", "english","latin","english","english"), name=c("marinus thingus", "aquaticus stuffae", "blob","water being","marine creature","altermarinus stuffae","other marine stuff", "unknown thingy"))

  num_sp num_name language                 name
1    100        1    latin      marinus thingus
2    101        1    latin    aquaticus stuffae
3    101        2  english                 blob
4    101        3  english          water being
5    101        4  english      marine creature
6    102        1    latin altermarinus stuffae
7    102        2  english   other marine stuff
8    103        1  english       unknown thingy
```

i want to have a correspondance table to be able to get the latin name from the english name. I think that table should give me the languages in columns and only num_sp id in row, which corresponds, i thing to a `pivot_wider`, except my "num_sp" is not a unique identifier, so the function gives the warning:

```
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
```

is there a way (throught the values_fn, maybe?) to get those list-cols to be splitted into different rows, to have a table like this:

```
 num_sp            english                latin
1    100               <NA>      marinus thingus
2    101               blob    aquaticus stuffae
3    101        water being    aquaticus stuffae
4    101    marine creature    aquaticus stuffae
5    102 other marine stuff altermarinus stuffae
6    103     unknown thingy                 <NA>
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can renumber the `num_name` column, cast the data to wide and `fill` the values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

species_list %>%
  group_by(num_sp, language) %>%
  mutate(num_name = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = language, values_from = name) %>%
  fill(latin, english) %>%
  ungroup
  

#  num_sp num_name latin                english           
#   <dbl>    <int> <chr>                <chr>             
#1    100        1 marinus thingus      NA                
#2    101        1 aquaticus stuffae    blob              
#3    101        2 aquaticus stuffae    water being       
#4    101        3 aquaticus stuffae    marine creature   
#5    102        1 altermarinus stuffae other marine stuff
#6    103        1 NA                   unknown thingy
```

Comment: thanks! i had seen several times the "row_number" solution, but as i had already 2 id columns and none did the job, i did not think this would work. I could not find the right combinaison of variables to put in the "group_by". And i did not know "fill" either so that great!

Answer (score 3):

THis will solve the issue

```
species_list %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = num_sp, 
                             names_from = language, 
                             values_from = name, 
                             values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(-num_sp)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  num_sp latin                english           
   <dbl> <chr>                <chr>             
1    100 marinus thingus      NA                
2    101 aquaticus stuffae    blob              
3    101 aquaticus stuffae    water being       
4    101 aquaticus stuffae    marine creature   
5    102 altermarinus stuffae other marine stuff
6    103 NA                   unknown thingy
```

Comment: Of course! i knew there was a very simple answer to that. thanks a lot!

Comment: when using your solution for my real data set, i have this error message : Incompatible lengths: 3, 2. I guess it's because at some point in the data,one of the languages has two version and another one has three? Would you know how to deal with that?

Comment: That may not be the issue? See more closely to find out the differences from sample dataset